# Как перехватить URL адреса открытой страницы в firefox?

Tags: javascript, firefox

Как перехватить URL адреса открытой страницы в firefox?

Comment: гугль в помощь! "дайте" звучит не для этой темы.

Comment: location.href?

Answer (score 1):

```
alert(window.location.hostname);

или 
alert(location.hostname);
```

хотя, не понятно что вкладывается в понятие "перехватить"..